# three linux servers serving one website?

Tags: webserver

My website suffers a lot of DDoS attacks and I was wondering in this technical day and age is it possible to serve one website with three hosts all with the same content so if one server gets taken down by a DDoS attack the whole website doesn't go down?

Is that even a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly a thing but we would need more info about your setup.  If you are just serving a static webpage, throwing a loadbalancer in front of the machines and have it round robin to the servers.  If you have something less static.  You would probably need a load balancer (or reverse proxy like nginx) in front of your web servers and a single database that all the servers use.

You might also look at a Content Distribution Network (CDN) like cloudflare.com or Akamai.com.

Here's a link about content delivery networks:

[Content Delivery Network - WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

You'll probably get a better answer with a little more info about your site

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this, here are some :

One is to put a load balancer in front of multiple web servers, useful if the servers can't keep up with processing the large amount of requests. Note that it will not save you from bandwidth-exhausting DoS attacks, in this case the only solution is to have more bandwidth than the attacker. Also the load balancer should have enough bandwidth and resources to support the traffic.

Another solution is to use round-robin DNS, in which case the two servers run independently and requests to them are distributed by the DNS server answering with either one of the server's addresses; this doesn't require a load balancer but will allow greater downtime if one server goes down (because DNS responses are cached and the clients should make a new request to get the address of the other, working web server).

Answer (score 1):

You can load balance your servers.  There are appliances out there that can do it and I'm sure some software solutions as well.  DNS is also something you can look into where all three of the servers can respond to requests for your www.site.com address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it many ways.
1. The poor mans way with round robin DNS - More info:

[Round Robin DNS - WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

2. The high tech way with a load balancer that balances load based on connections. more info:

[Load Balancing - WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29)